# How to fix 404 error for proxy_pass using rewrite?

Tags: nginx, static-files, proxypass

```
location /projects/test/2.0.0 {
#  modsecurity on;
  rewrite ^/(.*) /projects/test/2.0.0$request_uri break;
  proxy_pass http://10.1.0.6:3000/;
}
```

At http://10.1.0.6:3000; statics react, I get an html file.

It needs css and js at /static/js/123.js.

It tries to get them at https://example.com/static/js/123.js

And they are available at https://example.com/projects/test/2.0.0/static/js/123.js

How can I set this up correctly so the file can get the resources it needs?

Comment: Not related to Nginx. I think [this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/1084094/nginx-react-server-will-only-look-for-static-assets-at-root/1084145#1084145) can be useful.

Comment: I closed this issue by teaching my application to take paths from environment variables, changing them in CI, thx u! - i do this 2 days ago